# O ggplot aparece vazio: os dados não aparecem

Tags: r, ggplot2

Quero criar um `ggplot com as frequências em que aparecem as detecções de uma espécie de peixe. Mas, quando rodo, plota o gráfico sem os dados das frequencias das detecções, o quadro fica vazio. Como resolver?

Seguem alguns dados para reprodução:

```
ID          Freq
               0
Ana          390
Boca        2764
Joana          3
Cabelo      3276
Fabiane       10

table(myc_t$ID)->det_id
as.data.frame(det_id)->det_id
names(det_id)<-c("ID","Freq")
head(det_id)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(det_id, aes(x = "ID", y = "Freq")) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Ana", "Boca", "Joana", "Cabelo", "Fabiane", "Manu")) +
  labs(x = "Nomes dos indivíduos marcados", y = "Frequencia de detecção") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))
```

Gera o gráfico, mas sem valores e aparece a mensagem de erro:

> Warning message:
>   Removed 16 rows containing missing values (position_stack).

**Dados**

```
det_id <- read.table(text = "
ID          Freq
''             0
Ana          390
Boca        2764
Joana          3
Cabelo      3276
Fabiane       10
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Tente corrigir `aes(x="ID",y="Freq")` para `aes(x = ID,y = Freq)`. Isso já é um bom começo.

Comment: @RumenickPereira Com essa correção funcionou à primeira.

Comment: Sim, falei que é um bom começo, pois trata-se de uma nova contribuidora. Rsrs.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, pode sinalizar que é um comentário útil, por favor.

Comment: @RumenickPereira Não percebo, sinalizar o seu comentário? Já fiz.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, desculpa, não tinha visualizado ainda.

Comment: Só uma dica: pode usar `geom_col()`, que é um *alias* para `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`

Comment: Funcionou galera! Obrigada!

Comment: Só algo estranho no resultado. O número de detecções saiu diferente da tabela matriz. Os indivíduos "Fabiane" e "Manu" por exemplo tem muuitas detecções, mas quando peço para ler a quantidade de detecções head(det_id) o resultado é bem menor. (obs. A tabela matrix tem mais de 50 mil linhas).

Answer (score 4):

Conforme falado no primeiro comentário, basta tirar as aspas de ID e Freq.

Assim teríamos:

```
ggplot(det_id, aes(x = ID, y = Freq)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Ana", "Boca", "Joana", "Cabelo", "Fabiane", "Manu")) +
    labs(x = "Nomes dos indivíduos marcados", y = "Frequencia de detecção") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para tirarmos alguma lição disso, porque isso aconteceu?

Bem o [ggplot](/questions/tagged/ggplot) usa o que chamamos de *Non-Standard Evaluation* (NSE) que é, dizendo de forma muito grosseira, a capacidade do `R` de ler o texto do código passado e não o seu conteúdo. Dentro de todo o [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) ele é usado porque permite digitar menos eliminar decessidade de i) usar aspas e ii) se referir repetidamente ao objeto inicial (`ID` no lugar de `det_id$ID` ou `det_id[["ID"]]` ou mesmo `"ID"`).

Para usar a *standard evaluation* (caso precise em algum contexto) você pode usar a função `aes_string()`

```
ggplot(det_id, aes_string(x = "ID", y = "Freq")) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
        scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Ana", "Boca", "Joana", "Cabelo", "Fabiane", "Manu")) +
        labs(x = "Nomes dos indivíduos marcados", y = "Frequencia de detecção") +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)
```

Mais informações sobre NSE podem ser encontradas [aqui](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/metaprogramming.html).

Answer (score -1):

```
ggplot(det_id, aes(x = ID, y = Freq)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Ana", "Boca", "Joana", "Cabelo", "Fabiane", "Manu")) +
    labs(x = "Nomes dos indivíduos marcados", y = "Frequencia de detecção") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))
```